# get last 10 items in dynamodb cross partitions

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I've a table containing blogs posted by different persons;primary key is author+time;
**how to query last 4 blogs ordered by time?**(get blog6,blog3,blog5,blog4)

[image]

If I create a global secondary index(i.e.: I create a new attribute calling status,setting all values to "ok"),set status+time as primary key

[image]
I know I can resolve my question. But the result is:**all data in index will be stored in only one partition**

will it cause any weakness？

Comment: For your first question, would you query by author and get last 4 recent post? For the second question, how many maximum items are expected to be available for the status+time combination? If you can give me some rough figure, it will be easy to advice.

Comment: i want to get blog6,blog3,blog5,blog4 ordered by time,not blogs belonging to the same author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're on the right track. You are absolutely right about queries. They only give you the records for a given partition key.

If you need data ordered by time, regardless of partition key, then you will need to use a global secondary index.

Your idea of creating a GSI on `Status` is a step in the right direction but unfortunately, as you suspected, it would create pressure on your index because it would force all records in the index to be in the same partition. This pretty much defeats the scalability of DynamoDB.

But all is not lost. You could create an attribute that is a coarse representation of the timestamp of your records. An example might be to use the month, or day of year. This would allow records to be placed in up 12 partitions for the former, or 365 partitions for the latter. The compromise is that you would need a couple of queries to find out the most recent entries instead of a single query, though performance-wise it would be much better.

Yet another possibility, depending on your needs, would be to create an external index. Maybe you could have your system keep a cache of the most recently created blog posts. As new posts are created they get added to the cache. As old posts get "old" they get evicted from the cache. You do have to resolve the persistence problem but you could also rebuild the cache if need be by scanning your table.

Or you could event use another Dynamo table (or a relational database) to store the most recent blog posts. As long as this set of recent posts is relatively small you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a sparse index (for example, status) is similar to creating another table with only the recent blog posts. Make sure that you are using the Sparse functionality (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForGSI.html#GuidelinesForGSI.SparseIndexes) that most of the blog posts will have 'null' as the value of this column. This way your index is going to be small and these lookups should be efficient.

One way to maintain the small size of this index is to set the "older" records status to 'null', either do it every day (using a scheduled Lambda function) or for every new insert to the table (again using a Lambda function that is listening to the Updates stream of the table).

The recommendation to use a cache for these frequent lookups (every view to your web site needs it), it a good one. If you have a high hit rate, you should cache it, like any other repeating query.

Answer (score 0):

**how to query last 4 blogs ordered by time?**

This can be done using `ScanIndexForward` of `Query`. From [DynamoDB documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html):

> You can use the ScanIndexForward parameter to get results in forward or reverse order, by sort key.

For Java API, see [DynamoDBQueryExpression#setScanIndexForward](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBQueryExpression.html#setScanIndexForward-boolean-)

**All data in index will be stored in only one partion. will it casuse any weakness?**

Yes. It is not recommended to have all your data in one partition. See [guidelines for partitioning](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.UniformWorkload)

Comment: query only get result in the same partion.how to get "blog6,blog3,blog5,blog4" ordered by time?(i want to get newest blogs by time)