# How can I query Amazon dynamoDB to get recent 20 data in android?

Tags: android, amazon-dynamodb

Hi what I'm trying to do is getting recent data from my AWS dynamoDB.

In my database, the sort key is lastUpdatedDate and the partition key is userId.

I've found that I should set 'limit' as condition to get only 20 data.

But I don't know how to sort my data with my sort key.

Maybe I should get my largest lastUpdatedDate and sort with it, but I cannot do that.

Please help me!

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931520/get-last-10-items-in-dynamodb-cross-partions/39946372#39946372

Answer (score 0):

Please note that LIMIT has slightly different meaning compared to LIMIT available in some SQL databases.

**Limit:-**

> The maximum number of items to evaluate (not necessarily the number of
>   matching items). If DynamoDB processes the number of items up to the
>   limit while processing the results, it stops the operation and returns
>   the matching values up to that point, and a key in LastEvaluatedKey to
>   apply in a subsequent operation, so that you can pick up where you
>   left off. Also, if the processed data set size exceeds 1 MB before
>   DynamoDB reaches this limit, it stops the operation and returns the
>   matching values up to the limit, and a key in LastEvaluatedKey to
>   apply in a subsequent operation to continue the operation. For more
>   information, see Query and Scan in the Amazon DynamoDB Developer
>   Guide.

**ScanIndexForward:-**

> You can use the ScanIndexForward parameter to get results in forward
>   or reverse order, by **sort key**.

Comment: Do you know what is the default value for limit if you dont specify it when doing query or a scan?

Comment: Limit is optional. So, there is no default value. However, there is a default limit on the data set memory size I.e. 1 MB data as mentioned in the post.